# WPF Menu - unwanted borders

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, menu

I've made a simple WPF menu and changed its background and foreground colors, but there is still a border around the submenu itself and around each separator which I'm not able to remove:

[image]

**Xaml code:**

```
<Menu Style="{DynamicResource MainMenu}" IsMainMenu="true">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
       <MenuItem Header="_New" Command="New"/>
          <Separator />
          <MenuItem Header="_Import"/>
          <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
          <Separator />
          <MenuItem Header="_Print..." Command="Print"/>
          <MenuItem Header="_Print Setup..."/>
          <Separator />
          <MenuItem Header="_Sign Out" />
          <Separator />
          <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
       <MenuItem Header="_Edit"/>
       <MenuItem Header="_View"/>
       <MenuItem Header="_Tools"/>
       <MenuItem Header="_Help"/>
</Menu>
```

**Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}" x:Key="MainMenu">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2b2b2b"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#3f3f46"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3f3f46"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#3f3f46"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The white lines are part of the `Popup` template, which is what `MenuItem` uses at its default template. You'll have to override it to remove these linings.

If you have `Blend`, then you can easily change the template and copy-paste the code into your project. If you don't have Blend, give this a shot:

1- Add a reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero`

2- In your XAML file, import this namespace:

```
xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

Paste this code inside the `Window.Resources` section. This is what Blend generated based on the modified template:

```
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemSelectionFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#34C5EBFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#3481D8FF" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">M 0,5.1 L 1.7,5.2 L 3.4,7.1 L 8,0.4 L 9.2,0 L 3.3,10.8 Z</Geometry>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#8071CBF1"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#40FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuItemPressedFill" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#28717070" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#50717070" Offset="0.75"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#90717070" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <DockPanel Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="R1" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="B1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="L1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Fill="Transparent" Width="1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="T1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Fill="Transparent" Height="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="R1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="B1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="L1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="T1" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ContentContainer" Value="3,3,1,1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="0" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="100" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF959595" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3f3f46">
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="2"/>
            <DockPanel>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="SubMenuBorder" IsTabStop="false" Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#90717070"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="1" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="2"/>
            <DockPanel>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#90717070"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50FFFFFF"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#E0717070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemPressedFill}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#50747272"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#848589"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Bg" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerBorder" Margin="1" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="37"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#CDD3E6" BorderThickness="1" Background="#E6EFF4" CornerRadius="3" Height="22" Margin="1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="#0C12A1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                <Path Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="SubMenuBorder" IsTabStop="false" Template="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuContent, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="#D1DBF4FF"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemSelectionFill}"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Bg" Value="#8571CBF1"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF9A9A9A"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#EEE9E9"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#DBD6D6"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#848589"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,2,8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,3,2,3"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Let your `Menu` still use your `MainMenu` style, but have each sub `MenuItem` use the style Blend generated. For example, try

```
<MenuItem Header="_File" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}">
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Not sure how close this is to what you're looking for but should hopefully put you on the right track.