# WPF: How to remove menu popup border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want to remove menu's popup border. Not the menu items's border as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619093/wpf-menu-unwanted-borders) post.

This is a pic of my menu popup and I want to remove the white border the popup has.

[image: menu popup]

I am using mahapps library for my main windows with basedark theme. Also please be patient with me, as I am new to WPF and XAML.

Here are all the things I have tried-

1. Overwrote the border thickness and border brush of all the **"menu items"** with my custom style. This did not help as the border which I am interested is not tied to menuItems.
2. Overwrote the border thickness and border brush property of the **"menu"** element. This just changes the menu element when the mouse is not over it. Hope that made sense.

I need the element/control trigger/content-presenter the menu element possesses to disappear the menu popup border. Hope someone can help me in this regard.

Comment: You said you "overwrote the border thickness" does that mean you have tried setting the boarder thickness to zero with the custom style?

Comment: @DavidOesterreich Yea thats right. I overwrote it to 0 and I made the border brush to match the menuItems background without any luck. This says that the property I am looking for is tied to "menu" and not "menuItem". I do not know which property of "menu" fixes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was similar to the one asked here - [Removing thin border around the menuitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281529/removing-thin-border-around-the-menuitems)

I apologize for duplicating the question. I was of the thinking the property was tied to "Menu" but the property is still tied to "MenuItem".
Changing the "Padding" and "BorderThickness" to 0 of the popup's border solved my issue.

Comment: Can you show a sample of code demonstrating how changing values for popup solves this? I tried that and it has no effect.